# avarice from winavr not working with usb jtagice3

Tags: eclipse, avr, avr-gcc, avrdude, winavr

I am using win-avr with eclipse to build and debug my project with ATxmega256a3bu devie.
when I tried to debug the code using avarice using following command:

```
avarice --part atxmega256a3bu -mkII --jtag usb --read-fuses
```

it shows the following error

```
AVaRICE version 2.9, Jan  7 2010 22:42:57

Defaulting JTAG bitrate to 250 kHz.

did not find any USB device "usb"
USB device not found
```

how to detect jtagice3 using avarice in windows?

Comment: Well, is the driver installed? It comes as part of the AVR Studio installation.

Comment: yes, drivers are already installed with atmel studio. I can see the Jtagice3 in device manager as a JUNGO device. and with atprogram or atmel studio it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the libusb filter installed for that device avarice won't be able to find it.

You probably already have the Windows libusb port installed (if not, you can get it at http://libusb-win32.sourceforge.net); go to its bin/< platform > path and run install-filter.exe; then select your JTAGICE3 device.

Notice that once you have done this, your JTAGICE3 won't be visible to Atmel Studio anymore, unless you uninstall the libusb filter (using the same utility). If you need to go back and forth between avArICE and Atmel Studio, you'll have to repeat this cycle over and over (sorry...)

Another problem is that JTAGICE3 is not supported at least until avarice 2.13 (which is the latest at the time I'm writing this). I had to download the head sources and build them in cygwin to be able to use it. the flag you're using (-mkII) is for another model and won't work because their USB IDs are different.

Comment: I should also mention that, even though there is JTAGICE3 support code in the head sources, it is still currently a work in progress and not suitable for production use. You can do some basic things (run, pause, place breakpoints); but in my tests I found at least two showstoppers: it frequently quits due to protocol mismatches with GDB, and addresses are not matched correctly to source files / line numbers.